# MySQL beginner: How to set an user's host if there is no static public ip?

Tags: networking, ip, mysql, phpmyadmin, fritzbox

[image]

I want to **connect to a database called 'data'** of my web server from my **local raspberrypi**. To accomplish this, I have already set up a **user named raspberrypi** (using the web server's phpmyadmin UI), added a password, and *granted him all permissions on this database*.

My problem now is that I don't know **how to set the host variable**. My raspberry pi is only visible on the local network, it interacts via my fritz.box, which however only has a dynamic changing public ip.
*Is it safe to set the host to "%"? Or is there a better solution?*

Answer (score 0):

here is an approach that has worked for me in the past - use a service like No-IP (https://www.noip.com/) which keeps up with your dynamic IP address and maps a hostname to it.  Then your web app can point to a hostname for the database instead of an IP address.  I would rely on your firewall to ensure that only the IP address of your public web server is permitted to pass through to your database and then it is fine to set the host to '%'.